# Count in categories

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have data in the following form:

```
d = {'col1': ['State A','State A','State A', 'State B','State B'], 'col2': ['Town A', 'Town A', 'Town B', 'Town A','Town B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to use a groupby to get a count of how many occurrences of Town A and Town B are in State A and State B.  So something like

```
State A  Town A  2
         Town B  1
State B  Town A  1
         Town B  1
```

What's the syntax for this? The usual groupby returns an empty dataframe, since there are no other columns.

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2']).count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `['col2']` to fix your code

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col2'].count()
Out[150]: 
col1     col2  
State A  Town A    2
         Town B    1
State B  Town A    1
         Town B    1
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

If you need sort

```
df1=df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col2'].count().to_frame('value')

df1['helpcol']=df1.index.get_level_values(0)

df1.sort_values(['helpcol','value'],ascending=[True,True])
Out[164]: 
                value  helpcol
col1    col2                  
State A Town B      1  State A
        Town A      2  State A
State B Town A      1  State B
        Town B      1  State B
```

Comment: I know I didn't ask this, but is there a way to sort the counts within each group? Here they are sorted, but I know I would need to sort them myself in general.

Comment: @user21359 for example what kind of order you want? Can you show me that my friend

Comment: I mean order the counts in ascending or descending order within each state group, rather than have the towns ordered.

Comment: @user21359 I know :-) that is not you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2']).size()
```

Output:

```
col1     col2  
State A  Town A    2
         Town B    1
State B  Town A    1
         Town B    1
dtype: int64
```

And, you cand use to_frame() or reset_index() to get a dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

### Counting values in subgroups

The output you are looking for is achieved by [pandas.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
>>>  pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)

col2     Town A  Town B
col1
State A       2       1
State B       1       1
```

---

If you wanted Multiindex, I suggest adding [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to the previous command:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2).stack()

col1     col2
State A  Town A    2
         Town B    1
State B  Town A    1
         Town B    1
```

---

If you really want to use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), follow it with `.size()`:

```
>>> df.groupby(['col1','col2']).size()

col1     col2
State A  Town A    2
         Town B    1
State B  Town A    1
         Town B    1
```